# Extract SOAP message from MIME attachemnt

Tags: java, string, soap

I have a MIME attachment which contains SOAP message stored as a string which looks like:

```
------=_Part_10_182815722.1522086113658
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
.....
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
...
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
------=_Part_10_182815722.1522086113658
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-ID: <635742060149828871>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
......
```

I thought I can extract it using `getSOAPPart()` before everything was wrote to `ByteArrayOutputStream` to store is as a string but it came up is not working I have expected.

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it done instead getting that as a string this was:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 soapMessage.writeTo(baos);
 String strSOAPMessage = baos.toString(getMessageEncoding(msg));
```

I have used method below which will transform only SOAP part of MIME multipart:

```
public static String printSoapMessage(final SOAPMessage soapMessage) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError,
        TransformerConfigurationException, SOAPException, TransformerException
{
    final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    final Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    // Format it
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

    final Source soapContent = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getContent();

    final ByteArrayOutputStream streamOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final StreamResult result = new StreamResult(streamOut);
    transformer.transform(soapContent, result);

    return streamOut.toString();
}
```